# Dropbox could not dismiss modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, dropbox-api

I have integrated dropbox in my application,After entering the username and password,when i try to dismiss the dropbox view controller it is not dismissing. i am using xcode4.2 with ios sdk5.Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in ios5 you have to use presentingViewController instead of parentViewController.

e.g.:

```
if (self.parentViewController) {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)] && self.presentingViewController) {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```