# Dropbox Dismiss modalview controller not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dropbox-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox could not dismiss modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166597/dropbox-could-not-dismiss-modal-view-controller)

I am integrating dropbox in my app,i am using ios5 sdk when i try to dismiss the modal view controller after getting the username and password,its not dismissing.i would like to know whether dropbox api is updated or not?,please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Please add some code - how are you dismissing and presenting the modal view?

Comment: What is the difference to the question you asked yesterday? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166597/dropbox-could-not-dismiss-modal-view-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[self dismissModalViewController:]` in iOS5 instead of `[self."somewhat" dismissModalViewController:]`

Comment: Thank you d.lebedev for your help,I solved this problem by dismissing the modal view controller in the -(void)loginControllerDidCancel:(DBLoginController *)controller{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
delegate method,actually when i was using the older sdk,i did not dismiss the view controller,it got dismissed itself when i click the cancel button in dropbox login view controller any how thank you once again.